# Alternative to Tableau Public

Tags: charts, visualization, analytics, tableau-api

I have multivariate data that I want to analyse. So far I found two programs that have great features: Tableau Public and Mondrian (more here: http://www.wikiviz.org/wiki/Tools). You can create connected plots and have heaps of filtering and display options. That is realy great, but what both do not have is a proper save option. In Tableau Public you can save it online, but thats not what I want.

Is there something similar to Tableau Public, but offline and with a "Save to File"-Option? (free would be nice as well ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Tableau Desktop has a 14-day eval period you could learn on. Unlike Public, you can save to your heart's delight. So if this is a one-off project, that might suffice.

I suspect you don't want to save to Public since -- well, it's public :)

...but if that's not a problem for you, you could save to Public, then download you viz directly from the website and view it with Public and/or Tableau Reader.

(Or you could break down and actually purchase the software :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the desktop version of Microsoft Power BI, this will solve your issues